Question about Japanese past tense and て form
I was curious as to why in this sentence, 乾いた熱風のふくこの島は、当時一つの国として、島の人々が自分たちで決まりを作り、平和に暮らしていました,
乾いた熱風 instead of 乾くて熱風 is used for dry, hot wind. Can anybody tell me what this grammar is called?

乾くて is not a valid form. The て-form of this verb is 乾いて (た-forms and て-forms are always the same except the last syllable) but 乾いて熱風 still makes little sense. 乾いている熱風 would be possible. Did you mean to ask how 乾いた熱風 is different from this, or do you only want to know what it's called?

I think you might have misunderstood something somewhere.
The ～くて ending is the conjunctive ("[this adjective] and [something else]") for so-called ～い adjectives.
However, 乾【かわ】く is a verb, meaning "to become dry".  As a verb, its conjunctive form would be 乾【かわ】いて, not *乾【かわ】くて.
Also, since this verb describes a momentaneous or instantaneous change in state (specifically "to become dry" as a change, not "to be dry" as a state), the past tense is used to talk about something that has already become the resulting state.  This is similar to how the instantaneous verb 死【し】ぬ ("to die") is used in the past-tense conjugation 死【し】んだ to describe someone or something that "has already died" → "is dead".
HTH!  

Without your answer, it would have never occurred to me that OP might have mistaken 乾く for an adjective. It might help to add that the 熱 of 熱風 is not working as an adjective and therefore 乾くて熱風 would still be wrong even if 乾くwas an adjective. (It would be either *乾い熱風 or *乾くて熱い風, which are both wrong, of course.)

Thanks so much! This makes a lot more sense now.
